# Array from API call is not sorting

Tags: angular, sorting, asynchronous, angular5

I am trying to retrieve data from API then sort by ISO date. In my component `ngOnInit()`:

```
messages: Message[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAccounts(); // populates accounts as well as messages
    this.sortMessages(this.messages);
  }
```

In my API call that populates the `messages` array:

```
getAccounts() {
    var myMessages = this.messages; // pass by reference
    this.apiService.getAccounts().subscribe(
      res => this.accounts = res.Items,
      err => console.log(err),
      () => this.accounts.forEach(function(acc) {
        if(acc.messages) {
          acc.messages.forEach(function(message) {
            myMessages.push(message);
          });
        }
      }));
  }
```

Attempting to sort:

```
sortMessages(messages) {
    messages.sort(function(a, b) {
      return (a.date < b.date) ? -1 : ((a.date > b.date) ? 1 : 0);
    });
    console.log('sorted: ', messages);
  }
```

Returned to console:
[image]

Expected:

The `message` at `[1]` should be at the end because it has the latest ISO date. However, my array is not being sorted at all. Does this have to do with asynchronous and these methods being called in `ngOnInit()`? Or am I missing something simple?

Comment: `getAccounts()` is asynchronous, so when you call `sortMessages` your array is still empty. Do the sorting in the subscribe

Comment: @bugs just figured that out when i went to log messages[0] and got undefined, will try to sort in subscribe

Comment: @bugs where exactly in the subscribe should I do the sorting?

Comment: Have you made sure the date is a date object like var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(d1); and not a string

Comment: @Legman It is an ISO date string

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting the expected result because when you're calling sortMessage your messages array is empty.

**Solution 1:**

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getAccounts(); // populates accounts as well as messages
    this.sortMessages(this.messages);
  }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAccounts(); // populates accounts as well as messages
  }

getAccounts() {
    var myMessages = this.messages; // pass by reference
    this.apiService.getAccounts().subscribe(
      res => this.accounts = res.Items,
      err => console.log(err),
      () => {
        this.accounts.forEach(function(acc) {
          if(acc.messages) {
            acc.messages.forEach(function(message) {
              myMessages.push(message);
            });
          }
         }
        this.messages.sort(function(a, b) {
         return (a.date < b.date) ? -1 : ((a.date > b.date) ? 1 : 0);
        });
        console.log('sorted: ', messages);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Still not sorting

Comment: try 2nd solution then.

Comment: Still unsorted for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving the pushing of messages into the success portion of the subscribe and putting the sort call into the finish portion:

```
getAccounts() {
    var myMessages = this.messages; // pass by reference
    this.apiService.getAccounts().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.accounts = res.Items,
        this.accounts.forEach(function(acc) {
        if(acc.messages) {
          acc.messages.forEach(function(message) {
            myMessages.push(message);
          });
        }
      });
      }
      err => console.log(err),
      () => this.sortMessages(myMessages));
  }
```